Wheel File Not Including templates Directory and Root Files in Python Package
Background:
I am new to using the standard Python packaging tools and have typically relied on custom tooling. However, I’ve decided to get a better understanding of the packaging process, but I’m running into an issue.
I’m trying to create artifacts for distributing my application, and I’ve successfully generated both an sdist file and a wheel file. While I could probably set up a process to install from the sdist file, I’m concerned that I might be missing something. The wheel file, however, is being generated with an incomplete inventory.
Project Structure:
.
├── bin
│   ├── conn_mgr.sh
│   └── ora_tapi.sh
├── config
│   ├── OraTAPI.ini
│   └── OraTAPI.ini.sample
├── controller
│   ├── conn_mgr.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── ora_tapi.py
├── lib
│   ├── config_manager.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── LICENSE
├── MANIFEST.in
├── model
│   ├── api_generator.py
│   ├── db_objects.py
│   ├── framework_errors.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── session_manager.py
│   └── user_security.py
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
├── setup.sh
├── templates
│   ├── column_expressions
│   │   ├── inserts
│   │   │   └── updated_on.tpt
│   │   └── updates
│   │       └── updated_on.tpt
│   ├── misc
│   │   ├── trigger
│   │   │   └── table_name_biu.tpt
│   │   └── view
│   │       └── view.tpt
│   └── packages
│       ├── body
│       │   ├── package_footer.tpt
│       │   └── package_header.tpt
│       ├── procedures
│       │   ├── delete.tpt
│       │   ├── insert.tpt
│       │   ├── select.tpt
│       │   └── update.tpt
│       └── spec
│           ├── package_footer.tpt
│           └── package_header.tpt
└── view
    ├── console_display.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── interactions.py
    └── ora_tapi_csv.py

setup.py File:
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="OraTAPI",
    version="1.0.6",
    description="Oracle TAPI Application",
    author="Your Name",
    author_email="your_email@example.com",
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,  # Include files from the MANIFEST.in
    package_data={  # Include non-Python files in specific packages
        "templates": ["**/*.tpt", "**/*.tpt.sample"],
    },
    data_files=[  # Include root-level files and other extras
        (".", ["setup.py", "LICENSE", "setup.sh", "requirements.txt", "README.md"]),
    ],
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "conn_mgr=controller.conn_mgr:main",
            "ora_tapi=controller.ora_tapi:main",
        ]
    },
)

MANIFEST.in File:
include *.sh
recursive-include bin *.sh

recursive-include templates *.tpt *.tpt.sample

include config/*.ini
include config/*.ini.sample

include LICENSE
include README.md

The Issue:
I’m creating the package by running the following:
source venv/bin/activate
python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel

Both the sdist and wheel files are created, but I’m finding that the wheel file doesn’t include my templates directory or any of its sub-directories and their contents. I notice that files from the root folder (such as README.md, LICENSE, etc.) are displaced to an OraTAPI-1.0.6.data/datadirectory.
Whether I use the MANIFEST.in file or not, I seem to get the same results.
What I’ve Tried:

Ensured include_package_data=True is set in setup.py.
Explicitly defined package_data in setup.py.
Double-checked that the templates directory is correctly included in MANIFEST.in.
Ran the python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel command multiple times after making changes.

Questions:

What do I need to do to ensure that the wheel file includes both the templates directory and root-level files like LICENSE, README.md, etc.?
Am I missing any steps in the packaging process to make sure the wheel is complete?

Update:
I forgot to mention that the modules discovered during deployment are deployed under the global site packages (something which I will avoid using a venv), but only Python modules are deployed - the templates are not:
clive@ryzen-mint:~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages$ ls -1
bump2version-1.0.1.dist-info
bumpversion
controller
lib
model
OraTAPI-1.0.6.dist-info
view



The conventional thing to do would be to create a src/oratapi directory and move all the code and data files into this directory and subdirectories of it. This would make things much easier to handle.

Since none of the directories seem to have an __init__.py you might want to try with find_namespace_packages() instead of find_packages().

https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html -- https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/setup-py-deprecated/ -- https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/modernize-setup-py-project/

Hi sinoroc. I have init.py files in my Python directories and the Python code directories 'module', 'view' and 'controller' are being included to the wheel file., although only entrypoint scripts seem to get deployed. Could this be for the reason you describe?

You should not use data_files, it is deprecated, and also there is no point in having the files you listed under data_files be listed in data_files to begin with, this is unnecessary. -- What you want is "package data". But as the name says, the data has to be in an importable package or a subdirectory of an importable package. I recommend you start with a minimal project ([mre)], I recommend this tutorial (pay attention to the directory structure) and build up from there one file at a time.

After looking at serveral resourced (and a link included by
sinoroc in the comments - thanks) and Youtube videos, I ended up reorganising my layout:
├── LICENSE
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── controller
    │   ├── conn_mgr.py
    │   └── ora_tapi.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── lib
    │   ├── config_manager.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── model
    │   ├── api_generator.py
    │   ├── db_objects.py
    │   ├── framework_errors.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── session_manager.py
    │   └── user_security.py
    ├── OraTAPI.csv
    ├── resources
    │   ├── config
    │   │   ├── OraTAPI.ini
    │   │   └── OraTAPI.ini.sample
    │   └── templates
    │       ├── column_expressions
    │       │   ├── inserts
    │       │   │   ├── created_by.tpt
    │       │   │   ├── created_by.tpt.sample
    │       │   │   ├── updated_on.tpt
    │       │   │   └── updated_on.tpt.sample
    │       │   └── updates
    │       │       ├── created_by.tpt
    │       │       ├── created_by.tpt.sample
    │       │       ├── updated_on.tpt
    │       │       └── updated_on.tpt.sample
    │       ├── misc
    │       │   ├── trigger
    │       │   │   ├── table_name_biu.tpt
    │       │   │   └── table_name_biu.tpt.sample
    │       │   └── view
    │       │       ├── view.tpt
    │       │       ├── view.tpt.lbase_sample
    │       │       └── view.tpt.sample
    │       └── packages
    │           ├── body
    │           │   ├── package_footer.tpt
    │           │   ├── package_footer.tpt.sample
    │           │   ├── package_header.tpt
    │           │   └── package_header.tpt.sample
    │           ├── procedures
    │           │   ├── delete.tpt
    │           │   ├── delete.tpt.sample
    │           │   ├── upsert.tpt
    │           │   └── upsert.tpt.sample
    │           └── spec
    │               ├── package_footer.tpt
    │               ├── package_footer.tpt.sample
    │               ├── package_header.tpt
    │               └── package_header.tpt.sample
    ├── setup.sh
    └── view
        ├── console_display.py
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── interactions.py
        └── ora_tapi_csv.py

I removed the setup.py and MANIFEST.in and went with the following pyproject.toml file:
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "setuptools-scm"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "OraTAPI"
version = "1.0.6"
description = "Oracle Table API Generator Application"
authors = [
    { name = "Clive" }
]

# Useful if publishing through PyPI
keywords = [
    "python",
    "oracle",
    "database",
    "plsql",
    "table api",
    "stored procedures",
    "views",
    "database triggers",
    "code generator",
    "automation"
]

# Metadata
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "Development Status :: 4 - Beta",
    "Intended Audience :: Developers",
    "Topic :: Database",
    "Topic :: Software Development :: Code Generators",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent"
]

# Specify the package directory
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]

[project.urls]
"Repository" = "https://github.com/avalon60/OraTAPI"

# Include additional resources
[tool.setuptools.package-data]
"*" = ["*.ini", "*.ini.sample", "*.tpt", "*.tpt.sample"]

# Declare scripts as dynamic
dynamic = ["scripts"]

# Scripts defined under `[project.scripts]`
[project.scripts]
conn_mgr = "controller.conn_mgr:main"
ora_tapi = "controller.ora_tapi:main"

NOTE: I didn't include the dependencies in the above.
It was this section which was critical:
*# Include additional resources
[tool.setuptools.package-data]
"*" = ["*.ini", "*.ini.sample", "*.tpt", "*.tpt.sample"]*

This caused the wheel file to start including the resources folder. However,  it didn't include the resources folders into the dist file. To get these to be included, I had to use this command:
git add src/**/*.ini src/**/*.tpt src/**/*.tpt.sample

Note that you need to use setuptools-scm for the above solution.
I was hoping that I would be able to get the entrypoint scripts working:
*# Scripts defined under `[project.scripts]`
[project.scripts]
conn_mgr = "controller.conn_mgr:main"
ora_tapi = "controller.ora_tapi:main"*

But this just didn't seem to work - nothing got placed in the venv/bin directory. Anyway, I came to the conclusion that deploying an application, which includes config files and templates that the end-user needs to modify, just wasn't that practical - they get hidden deep in the site-packages directory, e.g. venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages. If I had gotten the entrypoints working I may have considered having the program clone the config and templates to a more suitable location, but the juice didn't apear to be worth the squeeze.
At least I got to the point where I'd be able to develop a distributable package the newer way (using pyproject.toml).
Anyone interested may find this Youtube video useful, and educational. Especially the techniques used to handle your own packages:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6tALyc4C10&t=1613s

There is likely no need for an __init__.py in the src directory. You would likely never import src. -- There does not seem to be anything wrong with your entry points, this should work. Is there a main function in src/controller/conn_mgr.py?

If the user needs access to some files (config files, templates, and so on), then they should be placed in an appropriate directory, I recommend the platformdirs library for finding what the correct locations are. But note that moving user-facing files can not happen at install-time. The logic will have to be built-in the application, copying files to user directories will have to be done at runtime.

Hi sinoroc. The init.py file, placed directly under src is by accident. I think it must have been placed there by accident when I was refactoring back and forth, trying things out.
Thanks for the  platformdirs link, I'll take a look.
The entry points seem fine to me. Both controller scripts have main() functions. You can see them here:
https://github.com/avalon60/OraTAPI/blob/develop/src/controller/ora_tapi.py
https://github.com/avalon60/OraTAPI/blob/develop/src/controller/conn_mgr.py
Thanks.

That platformdirs module looks very useful - great tip!
